# Split array using empty array value as a mask

Tags: php

I have an array that includes empty values.
Is there any way to split array into chunks using empty value as a mask?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your array structure I think a simple foreach could do the job:

```
$a = array(
    1 => 'test',
    2 => 'test',
    3 => '',
    4 => 'test',
    5 => 'test',
    6 => '',
    7 => 'test'
);

$new_array = array();
$i = 0;

foreach ($a as $k => $v)
{
    if ( ! empty($v))
    {
        $new_array[$i][] = $v;
        continue;
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: Also, you can reassign keys after checking with `$new_array = array_keys($new_array)`. Its because if `$a` may contain a sequences of empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

If $values is the array, then

```
$i = 0;
foreach($values as $value)
{
  if($value != "")
  {
     $new[$i][] = $value;
  }
  else
  {
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Hope, this wil help.